# A variation of Lévy's characterization of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245774/show-that-fw-t-frac12-int-0t-fw-s-ds-is-a-martingale-without-u), without using stochastic calculus, that if $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, then 
$$
f(W_t)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(W_s)ds
$$
is a martingale, where $f\in C^2$ and compactly supported. According to Problem 4.4 in Chapter 5 of Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*, the converse is also true. Namely, if $W$ is a continuous adapted process with $W_0=0$ such that
$$
f(W_t)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(W_s)ds\tag{1}
$$
is a martingale whenever $f\in C^2$ and compactly supported, then $W$ is a standard Brownian motion. This is essentially part of the proof of Lévy's characterization of Brownian motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A martingale is characterized by its characteristic function.

- apply the property with $f(x) = x$ proves that $W$ is a martingale
- fix $u$ and apply with $f(x) = \exp(iux)$; define 
  $g(u, t) = \mathrm E(\exp(iuW_t)); M(t) = 
  f(W_t) - \frac 12\int_0^t f''(W_s) ds$ 
  and you get
  $$
  1 = M(0) = \mathrm EM(t)
  = g(u,t) + \frac 12 u^2\int_o^t g(u, s) ds
  $$

whose solution is
$$
g(u, t) = \exp\left(-\frac 12 u^2 t\right)
$$

From this, you get that $W$ is a brownian motion.

Comment: you didn't show independence of increments of BM.

Comment: The second characterisation is easy: take $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: @mookid Of course I will, but could you please complete your chosen method of proving this, by showing that the increments are stationary and independent?

Comment: @theLowerCrust I think that you can find quite a complete proof here: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~njn/MM24/levy.pdf

Comment: @mookid The functions $f(x) := x$ and $f(x) := x^2$ don't have a compact support. And in the question it is only assumed that the martingale property holds for compactly supported functions $f$. Moreover, your answer doesn't show that the process is a Brownian motion; the only thing you prove is that $W_t \sim N(0,t)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

> The assumption holds for all $f \in C_b^2$, i.e. functions which are twice differentiable and have bounded continuous derivatives.

To this end, pick a function $\chi \in C^2_b$ such that $0 \leq \chi \leq 1$, $\chi(x) = 1$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $\chi(x)=0$ for all $|x|>2$. Then the function

$$f_n(x) := f(x) \cdot \chi \left( \frac{x}{n} \right), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}, \tag{1}$$

is twice differentiable and has compact support. By assumption,

$$\mathbb{E} \left( f_n(W_t) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f_n''(W_r) \, dr \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) = f_n(W_s) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^s f_n''(W_r) \, dr$$

for all $s \leq t$. Definition $(1)$ implies that $$\|f_n\|_{\infty}+ \|f_n'\|_{\infty} + \|f_n''\|_{\infty} \leq C$$ for some constant $C>0$ (which does not depend on $n$). Therefore, it follows from the continuity of $f,f''$ and the (conditional) dominated convergence theorem that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( f(W_t) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(W_r) \, dr \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) = f(W_s) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^s f''(W_r) \, dr.$$

**Step 2:**

> $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion.

The claim is proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977183/) (note that, by the first step, the assumptions in the linked question are satisfied). Don't hesitate to ask if you don't get along with it (notation is a bit different there).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and comment. mookid actually provided a link which showed how to complete the argument and obtain independence. So it remained to approximate $f$ as you did, which I was actually fine with. But I definitely appreciate your careful answer, which I'm sure will also help others on this site.